# does Alsa utility arecord interpolate captured samples?

Tags: audio-recording, alsa

I am working on some code to record audio using the ALSA API. I configure, then capture, then write captured samples out to a wav file. I configure ALSA for S32_LE, signed 32 bit samples. The  data I am capturing has the 1st byte of every 4-byte sample equal to 0x00, so it appears that my hardware is effectively only capturing 24 bits samples. This is reasonable to me for numerous reasons.

However, when I play back the wav file, the sound is distorted. The audio is there, I can tell the samples are mostly correct, but the capture is very distorted, so something is wrong.

When I use arecord using the same configuration I used for my code, the recording is perfect, no distortion. So I know the hardware is good (and my code is bad).

This is what I do not understand. When I compare the wav files, that is, the wav file my code generated and the wav file arecord generated, the wav file headers are *exactly* the same (except for the chunk length values of course). So my wav file generation appears correct.

However, the sample data in the arecord capture does NOT have a 0x00 in each sample word like my code captures. It appears that arecord is indeed capturing 32 bit samples from my sound card. But when my code uses the same configuration for 32 bit samples, every sample has the 1st byte of 0x00.

Am I missing some ALSA configuration options?

My code uses snd_pcm_hw_params_get_sbits() to retrieve the effective sample word size and it indeed returns 32 for the number of sample bits. I have studied the source code for the ALSA utilities aplay/arecord and I cannot find any clues as to whether arecord is changing the captured samples in any way.

In summary, why does arecord capture 32 bit samples from hardware that will only give me 24 bit samples?

Thanks,

-Andres

Comment: Are you using exactly the same device name and sample rate as with arecord?

Comment: yes I am...exactly the same.

Comment: Please show the arecord command, and the device configuration code.